# Permissions denied from cmd but not from git bash with multiple ssh keys

Tags: git, bash, ssh

I have two ssh keys for two bitbucket users on my Windows 7. 
`~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/bit_rsa`.

And config file as described in [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git). Also I update `.bashrc` to load ssh-agent.

1) ssh -v -t git@bitbucket.org from **git bash**

http://pastebin.com/pAk9rkvH

2) ssh -v -t git@bitbucket.org from **cmd**

http://pastebin.com/vbUcNwcW

Also `ssh-add -l`
**cmd**: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

**git bash**:
$ ssh-add -l
2048 43:7c:d6:4b:0d:26:5f:1c:d1:d2:61:17:0c:7d:0b:56 /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rs
a (RSA)

What the problem? Why I can't to login over ssh from cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my problem relates only to server windows.

I fixed it:

1) remove .ssh folder in c:\Program Files (x86)\Git
2) add your ip address to `known_hosts` via `git bash` (e.g. ssh -t git@bitbucket.org)
3) copy .ssh folder from c:\users\username.ssh to c:\Program Files (x86)\Git with correct `known_hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-agent` must be running and `ssh` uses the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env var for the connection info necessary to connect ssh-agent.  `ssh-agent` is started and the env var is set (NOET: value is dynamic, not fixed) when you start ssh-agent in your .bashrc in (git-)bash:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
echo succeeded
chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
. "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
```

Your `cmd` shell does *not* use `.bashrc` so `ssh-agent` isn't running (unless you are running (git-)bash and `cmd` in parallel.  If you are running them in parallel or `ssh-agent` is otherwise running, then `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` not set in your `cmd` shell.

Comment: Hm. I run git bash and check that ssh-agent is running. After that I run cmd and check connection. Permissions still denied

Comment: It looks like cmd doesn't look at `config` file and simple use id_rsa key